# Using SPDY as an underlying transport for SOA related implementations

Tags: rest, soap, soa, spdy

The goal of SPDY is to reduce the latency of web pages and make the web faster. It has been proven a significant reduction in page loading.

So if we use SPDY as an underlying transport for SOA related implementations (ex: SOAP message transmission, REST over SPDY), would it be beneficial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would.

SPDY is a more efficient protocol than HTTP. The main benefits that you will get for SOAP/REST communication are the fact that SPDY can do HTTP header compression, reducing bandwidth, and multiplexing - that is being able to send multiple requests on the same physical connection.

For a SOAP/REST use case you will not benefit of the big performance boost that SPDY Push gives (see [demo video](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/10/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/)), but it will be worth nonetheless.

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) is a Java Server that [supports SPDY](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html).

Comment: -1: Please edit your answer to show your relationship with Jetty. Otherwise this is close to spam.

Comment: It's in his profile, though it does help @sbordet if you put a disclaimer in any answer suggesting your products (Stack Overflow is _very_ sensitive to this sort of thing)